# The default '---Select--' is not coming in the razor drop-down while loading that drop-down on button click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

The value is getting populated in the drop-down but the default value `--select--` is not coming on top of drop-down populated list.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HoursVal, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0, 24)), "--select--")
```

Comment: I have it on top with your code. But if you have filled `model.HoursVal` `DropDownListFor` will select this value not default. It just how it's working.

Comment: Have you tried forcing a cast of "--select--" to string? `(string)"--select--"`

Comment: Can you show the HTML that gets rendered? What is the value of `model.HoursVal`?

Comment: (String)"--select--" is not working @JohnnyClara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that `HoursVal` is an integer so it's default value is 0 and since your select list is `new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0, 24))` which has `0` value as well it will always be selected in case that `HoursVal` property is not set for a specific value. If for example `HoursVal` was `int?` or a `string` and you won't set is to any value (leave it null) your dropdown will select the `--select--` option.